# How can I stop my player from glitching through my platform?

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm making a small project and I can't understand why my player keeps going up and down when it collides with my platform even when I want it to be static. The problem is in the code below and I can't find a fix.

```py
def Collision_Manager():
    if player.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
        if abs(player.rect.bottom >= platform.rect.top):
            player.y = platform.y - player.height
```

I cant understand why it's not a seamless animation like my border system which I did by doing this.

```py
def player_borders():
    if player.x <= 0:
        player.x = 0
    elif player.x >= 870:
        player.x = 870
    if player.y <= 0:
        player.y = 0
    elif player.y >= 570:
        player.y = 570
```

Comment: Are you sure your platform has a property `y`? The problem may be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, my platform does have a `y` property.

Comment: You are doing abs() on a condition that returns True or False (for some reason.)

Comment: The problem appears to be in other parts of the code than the bits you are showing, or possibly in the overall structure.

Comment: `abs()` is completely useless here. It doesn't any harm, however, since it's `abs(True)` or `abs(False)`, which results in 1 or 0.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help btw =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player.y` and `platform.y` are floating point coordinates. [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects however can just store integral coordinates.

The issue is caused when the `.rect` attribute is updated with the player's position and the coordinates are truncated. e.g.:

```py
self.rect.topleft = int(self.x), int(self.y)
```

A possible solution might be to [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates:

```py
self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```

Or round up the `y` coordinate:

```py
self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), int(math.ceil(self.y))
```

---

Depending on the control flow of your code, it may also be necessary to update the `.rect` attribute when a collision is detected:

```py
if player.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
    if player.rect.bottom >= platform.rect.top:
        platform.rect.bottom = platform.rect.top
        player.y = platform.rect.y
```

By the way, `abs()` is completely useless here:

<s>`if abs(player.rect.bottom >= platform.rect.top):`</s>

```py
if player.rect.bottom >= platform.rect.top:
```

It doesn't any harm, however, since it's `abs(True)` or `abs(False)`, which results in 1 or 0.

---

Minimal example (see also [Platform collision](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_platformer.md#platform-collision)):

[image]

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    JUMP_ACCELERATION = -7
    def __init__(self, midbottom_pos):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill("red") 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = midbottom_pos)
        self.y = self.rect.bottom
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.acc_y = 0
    def jump(self):
        self.acc_y = Player.JUMP_ACCELERATION
    def update(self, platforms):
        self.vel_y += GRAVITY
        self.y += self.vel_y
        self.rect.bottom = round(self.y + 1)
        colliders = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platforms, False)
        if colliders:
            self.y = colliders[0].rect.top
            self.vel_y = self.acc_y
            self.y += self.vel_y
        elif self.y > window.get_height():
            self.y = 100
        self.acc_y = 0
        self.rect.bottom = round(self.y)

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    PLATFORM_SHIFT = 1.5
    def __init__(self, topleft_pos):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((200, 10), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill("gray") 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = topleft_pos)
        self.x = self.rect.x
    def update(self):
        self.x -= Platform.PLATFORM_SHIFT
        self.rect.x = round(self.x)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

GRAVITY = 0.2
platfrom_group = pygame.sprite.Group(Platform((0, 250)))
player = Player((50, 100))
plyer_sprites = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(player)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    acc_y = GRAVITY
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.jump()

    platfrom_group.update()
    while platfrom_group.sprites()[-1].rect.right < window.get_width():
        last_platform_rect = platfrom_group.sprites()[-1].rect
        if last_platform_rect.top - 50 < 150:
            new_y = last_platform_rect.top + 50
        elif last_platform_rect.top + 50 > window.get_height() - 50:
            new_y = last_platform_rect.top - 50
        else:
            new_y = last_platform_rect.top + (50 if random.random() > 0.5 else -50)
        platfrom_group.add(Platform((last_platform_rect.right, new_y)))
        print(len(platfrom_group.sprites()))
    player.update(platfrom_group)

    window.fill((0, 0, 64))
    platfrom_group.draw(window)
    plyer_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```